# Mocking instance methods in python unittest

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, python-unittest

I'm a software developer for several years but new to python. I'm writing a unit test (so no database connection present) that involves a model in Django that accesses another model referenced via a foreign key connection. I want to mock the method that accesses this connection and replace the result with a hard coded response, that is different for each instance though.

Here's a minimal example:

```py
### tests/test_MyTestCase.py

from unittest import TestCase
from djangoapi.models import *


class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.instance1 = MyModel()
        self.instance2 = MyModel()

        foreignKey1 = MySubModel()
        foreignKey1.my_value = 1

        # Mock that self.instance1.submodel_set.all() returns [foreignKey1]
        
        foreignKey2 = MySubModel()
        foreignKey2.my_value = 2

        # Mock that self.instance2.submodel_set.all() returns [foreignKey2]

    def testSomething(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.instance1.get_max_value(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(self.instance2.get_max_value(), 2)

        
### models.py

from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    def get_max_value(self):
        value = 0
        # the return value of self.submodel_set.all() is what I want to mock
        for model in self.submodel_set.all():
            value = max(value, model.my_value)
        return value


class Submodel(models.Model):
    my_model = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    my_value = models.IntegerField()
```

I tried several combinations of `the @patch decorator`, `Mock()` and `MagicMock()` but could not get it to work. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I found out that the main problem was that the mocking can't happen in the `setUp` method, but must be done in the test methods themselves. This means some code duplication, but at least it works now. For reference, here's the working example:

```py
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch
from djangoapi.models import *


class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.my_model = MyModel()

        self.foreignKey1 = MySubModel()
        self.foreignKey1.my_value = 1

        self.foreignKey2 = MySubModel()
        self.foreignKey2.my_value = 2

    @patch('djangoapi.models.MyModel.submodel_set')
    def testSomething(self, mock_submodel_set):
        mock_submodel_set.all.return_value = [self.foreignKey1]
        self.assertEqual(self.my_model.get_max_value(), 1)

        mock_submodel_set.all.return_value = [self.foreignKey2]
        self.assertEqual(self.my_model.get_max_value(), 2)
```